My random number generator isn't generating new numbers
My project includes a function that generates three random numbers from the basket and maps each to a button. The idea is that each time you press a button you will get three new numbers and the number you pressed will be removed from the array. However, whenever the startTurn function is called, it spits out the same 3 numbers.
const repeat = (arr, n) => Array(n).fill(arr).flat();
let basket = repeat(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"], 3);

function newGame() {
  basket = repeat(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"], 3);
  console.log(basket);
  startTurn();
}


const button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
const button3 = document.querySelector('#button3');
const button4 = document.querySelector('#new-game');

let turncount = 0;
let choice = [];

function startTurn(){
  while(choice.length <= 3){
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (basket.length)) ;
    if(choice.indexOf(r) === -1) choice.push(r);
  }
  button1.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[0]];
  button2.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[1]];
  button3.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[2]];
  console.log(basket.length);
  console.log(basket[choice])
}


Add choice = []; inside the startTurn() and check again?

in repeat you not clone array,  (I was wrong about clone in fill :/ ), you need  map intead fill and there you can return destructed array)
make a fiddle right in stack overflow, there is button

A better approach would be to generate your choice array just once and simply shuffle it in startTurn(). You could use a Durstenfeld shuffle, as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75355871/2610061 .

The problem is caused by this
...
while(choice.length <= 3){
...

Since your choice array is declared at Global Scope, once it gets filled up, that's it. It will no longer be able to access that while loop.
As every time startTurn() is called, the same old choice array with initial 3 generations will keep on repeating.
If you want it randomized each time and still have choice accessible at Global Scope, then empty choice each time before the loop starts.
function startTurn(){
  // Empty choice, so that it regenerates
  choice = [];

  while(choice.length <= 3){
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (basket.length)) ;
    if(choice.indexOf(r) === -1) choice.push(r);
  }
  button1.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[0]];
  button2.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[1]];
  button3.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[2]];
  console.log(basket.length);
  console.log(basket[choice])
}

Here's a barebones working example


const repeat = (arr, n) => Array(n).fill(arr).flat();
let basket = repeat(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"], 3);

function newGame() {
  basket = repeat(["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"], 3);
  // console.log(basket);
  startTurn();
}


const button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
const button3 = document.querySelector('#button3');
const button4 = document.querySelector('#new-game');

let turncount = 0;
let choice = [];

function startTurn(){
  choice = []
  while(choice.length <= 3){
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (basket.length)) ;
    if(choice.indexOf(r) === -1) choice.push(r);
  }
  button1.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[0]];
  button2.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[1]];
  button3.style.backgroundColor = basket[choice[2]];
  // console.log(basket.length);
  // console.log(basket[choice])
}
.button {
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  color: white;
  background: #555;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<button class="button" id="button1" > Button 1 </button>
<button class="button" id="button2" > Button 2 </button>
<button class="button" id="button3" > Button 3 </button>
<button class="button" id="new-game" onclick="newGame()" > New Game </button>

</body>
</html>




Here is a rewrite of your JavaScript part using a simple shuffle for each game. I reduced the colors such that they will not be repeated in the buttons.


function shfl(a){ // Durstenfeld shuffle
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}
const basket = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"],
      btns=document.querySelectorAll("button[id^=button]");

function startTurn(){
  shfl(basket);
  btns.forEach((b,i)=>b.style.backgroundColor=basket[i]);
}
startTurn();
.button {
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;    
  color: white;
  background: #555;
}
<button class="button" id="button1" > Button 1 </button>
<button class="button" id="button2" > Button 2 </button>
<button class="button" id="button3" > Button 3 </button>
<button class="button" id="new-game" onclick="startTurn()" > New Game </button>



The whole application can be made even more felxible by allowing any number of buttons, see below:


function shfl(a){ // Durstenfeld shuffle
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}
function rndArr(choices,n){       // create a randomly shuffled array of arbitrary length,
                                  // with the lowest number of repetitions,
                                  // based on a limited number of choices.
                                  
 const ar=shfl(choices.slice(0)); // create a shuffled copy of the choices
 if (n>ar.length){                // requested target array is longer than the provided choices
   for(let i=ar.length;i<n;i++) ar[i]=ar[i-choices.length] // spread out the choices ...
   return shfl(ar)                                         // ... and shuffle them again
 } else return ar.slice(0,n)      // pick first n elements directly
}

function mkbtns(){
 bdiv.innerHTML=Array(+inp.value).fill(0).map((_,i)=>`<button class="button" id="button${i+1}"> Button ${i+1} </button>`).join("");
 btns.length=0;
 btns.push(...bdiv.querySelectorAll("button"));
 startTurn();
}
function startTurn(){
  const colors=rndArr(basket,btns.length);
  btns.forEach((b,i)=> b.style.backgroundColor=colors[i]);
}

const basket   = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"],
     [inp,bdiv]= ["count","buttons"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id)),
      btns = [];
mkbtns();
.button {
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;    
  color: white;
  background: #555;
}
<input type="number" id="count" value="3" placeholder="enter number of buttons ..." onchange="mkbtns()">
<div id="buttons"></div>
<button class="button" id="new-game" onclick="startTurn()" > New Game </button>



